# Add a timestamp to an image in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, image-processing

In .Net/VB.Net, what is the best way to embed a timestamp (simple text like "2011/Jan/13 13:44") into a bitmap image?

I am loading images from a database, and they come without a timestamp embedded directly in the bitmap. What I am trying to do is add a timestamp to the image when I save it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you mean that you want to paint a date/time onto the bitmap before dishing it up to somebody. If that's the case, then this link

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-draw-text-on-an-image

will show you the path to enlightenment. Basically, in C#, it's something like:

```
Bitmap   myBitmap = new Bitmap("C:\\myImage.jpg");
Graphics g        = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);

g.DrawString("My\nText", new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.White, new PointF(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to use the bitmaps as rendering surfaces and manually call the DrawText method on them.

Play around with the `Graphics` class and see if you can get one from a bitmap (Also see if Bitmap does not come with a `GetGraphics` function